# Combine Arrays with similar values into a new array

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
array(4) (
0 => array(3) (
    "id" => string(1) "2"
    "state" => string(8) "San Francisco"
    "options" => array(2) (
        "value" => string(1) "1"
        "label" => string(8) "SF1"
    )
)
1 => array(3) (
    "id" => string(1) "2"
    "state" => string(8) "San Francisco"
    "options" => array(2) (
        "value" => string(1) "2"
        "label" => string(6) "SF2"
    )
)
2 => array(3) (
    "id" => string(1) "1"
    "state" => string(7) "New Jersey"
    "options" => array(2) (
        "value" => string(1) "3"
        "label" => string(9) "NJ1"
    )
)
3 => array(3) (
    "id" => string(1) "1"
    "state" => string(7) "New Jersey"
    "options" => array(2) (
        "value" => string(1) "4"
        "label" => string(10) "NJ2"
    )
)
```

)

What I want to achieve is get an array with the options added on duplicate state names. So that I end up with San Francisco options having 2 arrays in it and so on for any other duplicate state names I get.

How do I do this in php?

What I would like to have is:

Combine the arrays so that the "options" part of "state" has the multiples. For example "San Franciso" would have its Options section as 2 arrays with SF1 and SF2. I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something similar:

```
$output_array = array();

foreach($input_array as $input){
    $output_array[$input['state']][] = $input;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/128616)

Comment: This is exactly what I had come up with. As you already posted yours, I've just added a demo to it. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: This creates a new array with by inserting the previous one in it and giving one of its keys the name of the array. I intend to end up with 2 arrays under $array containing all my values.